# What's the advantage to deploy 3D printing on IaaS

Tags: diy-3d-printer

3D printing is becoming more and more populated during the last few years. But still, only a few group of people can access the 3D printer and know how to use it. So it is reasonable to deploy 3D printing on the cloud, so that almost everyone can access it and finish their job in a few steps.

Basically, there are 3 types of service on the cloud, which are:

- **Iaas** - Infrastructure as a Service;
- **PaaS** - Platform as a Service;
- **SaaS** - Service as a service.

It seems we can deploy 3D printing on all of these models. But specifically, what's the advantage to deploying 3D printing on IaaS? Under what condition we should use IaaS?

Answer (score 2):

Most cloud models are based on virtual rather than physical services.

The closest thing I can think of as "IAAS" in the 3D printing space would be something like [3DHubs](https://www.3dhubs.com/) which connects people that have printer capacity with people that want to print.

The whole cloud 3D printing thing seem a bit questionable to how large/viable of a market it really is.  I know there are a LOT of people out there that want to make money off of (or at least defer the cost of) the printer they bought; but, the market seems over-saturated.  Heck, even [UPS](https://www.theupsstore.com/print/3d-printing) does it.

All the people that I know that use contract printing already have their own printer but contract out either for more volume, or a different material than they can print with their printer.  At work we have a printer; but, we go outside if we want volume (hundreds of pieces) but are not yet ready to commit to a mold.  When we go outside, we would only consider a trusted vetted supplier - not the cloud.